# 'super' key not working as expecting in Sublime Text 2 or 3 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-2

The [Sublime key binding docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html) suggest that the `super` (Windows key) is usable in user defined key bindings. I'm aiming to create the following style of mapping so I have consistency between my OSX and Windows machines:

```
[
    { "keys": ["super+left"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "bol", "extend": false} },
    { "keys": ["super+right"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eol", "extend": false} }
]
```

However they don't work as expected.

In testing I was able to get a mapping that uses the `super` key to work when combined with the `shift` key, for example:

```
[
        { "keys": ["super+shift+v"], "command": "paste" }
]
```

but removing the `shift` key from the mapping as follows resulting in the mapping no longer working:

```
[
        { "keys": ["super+v"], "command": "paste" }
]
```

Is there special / restricted behaviour with the super key that isn't documented?

I've tried this on both Sublime Text 2 and Sublime Text 3 now that the beta is open to the public. If I could sort these shortcut issues I'd purchase in a heartbeat.

Comment: Win+Left/Right are used by Windows itself. Win+V isn't, but I don't know why it doesn't work in ST.

Comment: What are Win+Left/Right used for in Windows? I've managed to map these keys in other apps using AutoHotKey but they aren't observed by Sublime Text. Note I tested the above with AHK disabled to avoid conflicts/outside influence but for reference the AHK mappings that work for other apps e.g. Visual Studio are: 

`; Win + Shift + Arrow Right = Win + End
;#+Right::#+End

; Win + Shift + Arrow Left = Win + Home
;#+Left::#+Home`

I'd be equally happy with a solution that allows AHK mappigns to work in Sublime Text.

Comment: "What are Win+Left/Right used for in Windows?" - You can easily try them out. Win+Left/Right/Up/Down = Maximise window to left half of screen, right half, completely maximise, restore down.

Comment: Ah, I had disabled these years ago... can't recall how but it could be that is causing the issues I'm seeing with Sublime Text. Will dig in.